# Update postmeta custom field for products WHERE sku is set in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, product

I have 2 different websites in Woocommerce. The products are exactly the same but one is an E-shop and the other is not, so i don't have prices in the second web site. I use the Exporter from Woocommerce for updating the second web site (to avoid doing same work twice). So i have created a php script and i run it manually every time that i have added new products to the secondary web site.

I have tried this inside a loop:

`UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='$row[mydocs]' WHERE meta_key='_wc_product_documents' AND post_id='$row[post_id]'`

This is working but the products doesn't have the same post_id in both database tables. The only same unique key is the '_sku' field. But sku is not a table column. How i can use the above mySQL query with sku? (i know how to get the _sku field from the first table but i don't know how to use it for the update query.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this in 2 steps, first find the post_id in the database you want to update, for example: `SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' AND meta_value = '$row[sku]'`

then use the value in `UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='$row[mydocs]' WHERE meta_key='_wc_product_documents' AND post_id='$post_id'`

Comment: Thanks man. This works great. I added an INSERT INTO for products that don't have the '_wc_product_documents' field in the second table but they have in the first table.

Comment: Cool, I am glad you figured it out!

Comment: btw. You could connect 2 sites via woocommerce rest api to sync them automatically so you don't have to run the script and export manually.